# How to fix CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while querying Google Big Query using Python (PyCharm)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am fairly new to Python and Google Cloud Platform.
I have a use case to execute a SQL command on BigQuery Platform and then place the output of the query in a file. I am using PyCharm IDE to run the Python command using a Windows 10 laptop.

I have the service account JSON available with me, which I am using to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS value. The command fails with the following error:

google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 120.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(functools.partial(<bound method JSONConnection.api_request of <google.cloud.bigquery._http.Connection object at 0x000001F69E5F2970>>, method='POST', path='/projects/<project_name_here>/jobs', data={'jobReference': {'jobId': '', 'projectId': '<project_name_here>', 'location': ''}, 'configuration': {'query': {'useLegacySql': False, 'query': '\nSELECT *\nFROM `bq-table-name-here`\nLIMIT 100\n'}}}, timeout=None)), last exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

The actual code that I am trying to execute is given below:

```
 import yaml
 import os
 import sys
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 from google.oauth2 import service_account
 from datetime import datetime
    
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] ="C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Code\\Creds\\creds.json"
    credentials = os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
    
    sql_script = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM `<project-name>.<dataset-name>.<table-name>`
    LIMIT 100
    '''
    
    client = bigquery.Client()
    location = 'asia-southeast1'
    
    query_job = client.query(sql_script,location=location).to_dataframe()
    query_job.to_csv('table_schema_extract.csv')
```

Would really appreciate help in terms of what I maybe doing wrong, which is causing this error.

Thanks & Cheers !
Suvrat

Comment: The error is caused by a self-signed certificate. Are you behind a proxy? Edit your question with details on your networking environment.

Comment: No, as per my awareness I am not behind a proxy. Do I need to setup any certificates to be able to run this query extract?

Comment: Based upon your answer you are behind a proxy. This means whoever manages the proxy has full access to your data. That includes your logins, passwords, email, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the way my organization's domain configurations work is that anytime I access any Google Account Authenticated service like GCP, Gmail, Google Drive etc. The browser's security certificate do not show up as the default Google certificates but instead shows my organization's certificate.

[image: Google Cert File]

I believe this has something to do with Google suit being used in my organization.
Every time I am using Python to access any of the Google cloud services it tries to use the default Google certificates instead of my organization's certificate. Since the way my organizations laptops domain configuration is done it doesn't allow this to get authenticated properly.
To fix this issue I had to manually extract the certificate file from my browser when I am accessing the Google cloud services page, this certificate file was then appended to the python's default certificate file. As soon as I then try to execute the same Python command it runs successfully without giving any issues. Remember to append the certificates from all the certificate levels when you access the cert file from browser and not juts the root or parent level cert only.
The way to know the Python certificate file location is that:

1. Do a: pip install certifi
2. Import the CERTIFI UTILITY: import certifi
3. Run: print(certifi.where())
   This will give you a path like: C:\Users<AccountName>\PycharmProjects<Projectname>\venv\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
   You just need to ensure that you append the Google certificates that you extracted from your browser into this .PEM file. This really took me some time to figure out, as I was apparently new with Python as well as SSL certification awareness.

Comment: Can you show us the steps to add google certificates to the >PEM file?